# Function/Dataflow model or UML models of Ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum

I am looking for models that are describing Ethereum or one of the clients, like geth (which basicly make up ethereum, right?)
Are there any of the common software models like function models or uml class diagramms as the picture below?  
 
It would really help me understand how ethereum actually works. 
 Sorry if this question is too basic.  
Thanks in advance[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wp8Ud.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look at ConsenSys's [EthOn](https://github.com/ConsenSys/EthOn), which allows Ethereum's ontology<sup>1</sup> to be shown diagrammatically.

> <sup>1</sup>An ontology is a formalization of concepts and relations within a
>   domain.

For example, the following diagram is a (very) simplified EthOn model of Ethereum:

[image: EthOn ontology example]

There's a good introduction to it in [this](https://media.consensys.net/ethon-introducing-semantic-ethereum-15f1f0696986) blog post, and if you want to jump straight to their pre-prepared examples, have a look in their [`img/` folder](https://github.com/ConsenSys/EthOn/tree/master/doc_resources/img) on GitHub.